# Proving (by induction) the inequality $ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt i} > 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1), \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: induction

Trying to prove that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt i} > 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1), \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

using induction.

My only attempt so far has consisted of squaring both sides (during the $P_{k+1}$ part) to get rid of square roots, but it turned real messy, real fast.

Tried using

$$\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac1{\sqrt i}\Bigg]^2 > \Bigg[ 2(\sqrt{k+1}-1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\Bigg]^2$$

but the algebra was just too dirty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**.  To make proof by induction work, you need a relationship (fairly simple if possible) between the statement for $k$ and the statement for $k+1$.  In this case the relationship is that the LHS for $k+1$ is equal to the LHS for $k$ plus one more term.  So you need to prove that
$$2(\sqrt{k+1}-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}>2(\sqrt{k+2}-1)\ .$$
If you do some working to eliminate the denominator, then eliminate the square roots, the algebra is not actually all that awful.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That got me over the finish line. I still think the algebra could have been nicer, but practice makes... something.

Answer (score 6):

*Hint*. How about using the inequality

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}
= \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{i}}
> \int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
= [2\sqrt{x}]_{i}^{i+1}
= 2\sqrt{i+1} - 2\sqrt{i}.
$$

Comment: That's certainly a very elegant way to show that inequality. Using that would have solved the induction step in seconds. Sadly, I don't see those kinds of opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

Trick is: $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{i}} > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i+1} + \sqrt{i}} = \sqrt{i+1} - \sqrt{i}$. Thus:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{i}} > \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sqrt{i+1} - \sqrt{i}\right) = \sqrt{n+1} - 1$.

Comment: Interesting! But I'm not very good with calculating sums, so how you found that last equality isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt i} > 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)$$ for some $n$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt i} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}  > 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
so it suffices to show that $$2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq 2(\sqrt{n+2}-1).$$ This is equivalent to showing
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq 2\sqrt{n+2} - 2\sqrt{n+1}$$
and in turn to
$$\sqrt{\frac{n+2}{n+1}} + 1 \geq 2(n+2 - (n+1))= 2$$
(by multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1}$. This last one is easily seen to hold, as $\sqrt{\frac{n+2}{n+1}} > 1$.

Comment: Nice! That's a way better algebra-run than I did. But I'm new to induction, so there are a lot of "givens" that I don't see, so I take a lot of detours.